# TradingView: 403 forbidden when trying to search for symbols

Tags: javascript, ajax, tradingview-api

Im developing an app that uses TradingView widget, and I have an access to their charting library API, I have many symbols, and I would like to match the chart to the symbol I have.

the best way Ive found is to use their search function and provide the symbol (for me, it always find the right token we need to show).

The problem is, I can not call this URL from my server, I can open it from the browser and I will see the results, see here for example:
https://symbol-search.tradingview.com/symbol_search/v3/?text=NISHIB&lang=en&search_type=crypto

but if I will try to call this URL from the server or Ajax call, I will get 403 forbidden error.

Now, I contacted tradingviews and I even have their charting library access, but I couldnt find a solution to search a symbol and get back the results.

Here is an example of (not working) code that return 403 error:

```
<script>
function loadDoc() {
  const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.responseText;
  }
  xhttp.open("GET", "https://symbol-search.tradingview.com/symbol_search/v3/?text=NISHIB&lang=en&search_type=crypto");
  xhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

you can run it here:

https://jsfiddle.net/hg43bdq6/

Thank you for your help.